# How to watch cravetv on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

Has anyone found a way to do this? I've tried using Miro but can't seem to get it to install properly on 16.04 following their instructions [here](http://www.getmiro.com/download/for-ubuntu/). On update it yells about a missing release file, and I can't get Miro to show up in software center/synaptic.

I don't want to use a VM if I don't have to. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing to cravetv on my smart tv now works with the latest software update for my tv. Not ideal because browsing is kind of a pain with a remote, but whatever. It'll have to do I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you are in Canada, cravetv is supported by most current web browsers. Adobe Flash is required. I have had good luck using Google Chrome with similar services.

Sources:

https://support.nwtel.ca/hc/en-us/articles/205455585-Do-I-need-a-specific-web-browser-to-access-CraveTV-

https://help.cravetv.ca/